# Built-In Type Vs. User Defined Type C++

Tags: c++, types, user-defined-types

Built-in Type Vs. User Defined Type  (C++)

So I have come across both of these two terms in course notes, and the use of them seems identical, however I have a feeling they each refer to a distinct type.
"A built-in type is a type that can be built from a fundamental type, using qualifiers and operators."
From my Course notes.

Would it be fair to say then that User Defined Types refer only to Classes & Structs whereas A built in type refers to pointers & Arrays?

Comment: Pointers and arrays are actually derived types. Built-in types are `char, int, float, double, etc...`

Comment: The section of the C++11 standard that talks about the fundamental types might be helpful. https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types

Comment: Yeah I wonder if my notes are using Built-in types as a synonym for Derived types then, because searching for Built in types yields little results, but I know they don't mean fundamental types. 

Thanks for the info

Comment: Fundamental Types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types  All the Types (Type Categories): https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type   You might want to refer to the source of the course notes for the origin of the terms you are using.

Comment: The C++ standard does not use the term "built-in type", your lecture notes are solely responsible for it.

Comment: That is what I was thinking, the notes we're given seem quite outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no strict definition of a user-defined type. However the Standard distinguishes in its descriptions fundamental types and user-defined types. If to follow the logic of the C++ Standard then any compound type except pointer types and references to fundamental types can be considered as a user-defined type.

Comment: @RichardCritten I made a typo. I mean the term compound type.